# How to play video locally in objective-c for iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to play the video on iphone locally by storing the video in  the app.
how can i do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To store video in the app, you can just add it with a copy files phase in the build. For an example of how to play a movie, check out the Media Player docs and especially the [MoviePlayer](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/MoviePlayer_iPhone/index.html) sample code.

Answer (score 11):

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myVideo" ofType:@"mp4"];   

MPMoviePlayerController *myPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
myPlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
myPlayer.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;
myPlayer.fullscreen = YES;
myPlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
myPlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;
myPlayer.contentURL =[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
[self.view addSubview:myPlayer.view];
[myPlayer play];
```

Comment: Nothing happened when I used this code. Nothing appeared on the screen. Nothing played. Ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Try the following code:

```
-(IBAction)Videoplay_btn:(id)sender
{
   NSString *videoPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Movie" ofType:@"m4v"];
   NSURL *streamURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoPath];
   MPMoviePlayerController *moviplayer =[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:     streamURL];
   [moviplayer prepareToPlay];
   [moviplayer.view setFrame: self.view.bounds];
   [self.view addSubview: moviplayer.view];
   moviplayer.fullscreen = YES;
   moviplayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
   moviplayer.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeNone;
   moviplayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
  [moviplayer play];        
}
```

Comment: Is there more to make this more stable? The Done button doesn't work. When the video ends the whole app is locked. The shrink from full screen button doesn't work. I take it these are all implementation details for the MPMoviePlayerController class.

Comment: Of note MPMoviePlayerController is deprecated for iOS9 according to Apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/index.html

Answer (score 0):

FYI

> The MPMoviePlayerController class is formally deprecated in iOS 9.
>   (The  MPMoviePlayerViewController  class is also formally deprecated.)
>   To play video content in iOS 9 and later, instead use the 
>   AVPictureInPictureController  or  AVPlayerViewController  class from
>   the AVKit framework, or the  WKWebView  class from WebKit.