# Viewing Websites on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Help me figure out please I'm new to developing for iOS using xcode

- How to view websites on another view controller using one storyboard in xcode?
- How to play embedded videos on another view controller?

Comment: Assuming you're talking about the iPhone simulator... You cannot download or install apps from the app store in xCode (simulator). You have to get an actual iPhone or iPad to test some of those things.

Comment: Go through these links: http://codewithchris.com/xcode-tutorial/ & http://codewithchris.com/demo-app-with-xcode-and-interface-builder/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do the following:

> 1. View websites in xcode.
> 2. Play local videos in xcode.
> 3. Download apps in xcode.

the reason - because [xcode is an IDE](https://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/)

xcode is used for developing apps. So I will assume that you really want to know how to program in xcode.

So:

> 1. View websites by implementing a [UIWebView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and using its [delegate methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).
> 2. To play local videos using objective-c see [How to play video locally in objective-c for iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324305/how-to-play-video-locally-in-objective-c-for-iphone)
> 3. And to determine if an app is installed on a device you can use [URL Schemes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html) and do the following:

```
 if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenUrl:theUrlYouWantToCheck]) {
     // Do whatever it is you want to do in here if that URL exists. 
     // You would probably do
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openUrl:theUrlYouWantToCheck];
 } else {
     // Do whatever it is you want to do if it doesn't exist.
 }
```

Comment: i found the answer


NSString *videoPath